# Separate Flask `app.route` blocks

Tags: python, flask

I have the following `route`ing function in `Flask` but as I build my application it gets too messy with too many links.

What should I do if I want to separate or group the routers in a separate file?

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/mylink', methods=['GET'])
def get_mylink():
    return render_template('mylink.html')
```

Or is it possible to `package`size the `route`rs? For example,

```
import myrouter
myrouter.Run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When my app was getting unwieldy, I split up the routes and functions into different files, but not quite exactly like you are suggesting/asking about.

If your app follows the typical package structure and has, for example, an index and blog page:

```
/app
  /templates
    /blog.html
    /index.html
  /__init__.py
  /models.py
  /views.py
```

then you could consider turning the `views.py` file into a directory called `views` and create a .py file for each set of related routes within that directory. For example:

```
/app
  /templates
    /blog.html
    /index.html
  /views
    /blog.py
    /main.py
  /__init__.py
  /models.py
```

You just put each set of `@app.route()` decorators and corresponding function into the appropriate file. So for the home page you could put this and any other general routes (like login/logout)

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

into `main.py` in the `views` directory. You would need to import these in the `app/__init__.py` with `from app.views import main, blog`. And don't forget to include a blank `__init__.py` file in the views directory.